# problems in "pandas datetime convert to num"

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I use pandas to read a csv file to do some analysis. But the returned type is pandas.core.series.Series, which can not be converted to num using the command matplotlib.dates.date2num. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AAPL = pd.read_csv(
    "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csvs=AAPL&a=0&b=1&c=2009&d=0&e=1&f=2010",
    parse_dates=['Date']
)

x = AAPL['Date']
y = AAPL['Close']
print type(x)
x = mdates.date2num(x)

z4 = np.polyfit(x, y, 6)
p4 = np.poly1d(z4)
xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
dd = mdates.num2date(xx)
plt.plot(dd,p4(xx))
```

The command `print type(x)` returns `pandas.core.series.Series`. This one `x = mdates.date2num(x)` returns the error as: `AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'.`

Any one can shed a light on me for this issue?

Comment: [`date2num`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) wants a list of `datetime.datetime`, not an array of `numpy.datetime64` objects. So you'll have to convert one to the other.

Comment: Do you know which command can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `x.astype(datetime)` to convert to `datetime`.

```
from datetime import datetime
x = mdates.date2num(x.astype(datetime))

z4 = np.polyfit(x, y, 6)
p4 = np.poly1d(z4)
xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
dd = mdates.num2date(xx)
plt.plot(dd,p4(xx))
```

Comment: Gives me `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'toordinal'` with matplotlib 1.5.0.

Comment: Seems to work with matplotlib 1.5.1 / numpy 1.10.4 / pandas 0.17.x (python 2.7 and python 3.4)

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like your command works well. But the other line has a problem,   File "prac.py", line 11, in <module>
    parse_dates=['Date'], the error message is 
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
DO you have idea why is that?

Comment: @MikeMüller, maybe `mdates.date2num(pd.Index(x).to_pydatetime())` works for you?