# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

i have,

```
x = [2017-06-07, 2017-07-19]
y = [155.98, 151.42]
```

i want to draw a straight line and find the y intercept(3rd point).
for now am using the polynomial fit method to a draw line.

```
x = [2017-06-07, 2017-07-19]
y = [155.98, 151.42]

coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
x_axis = np.linspace(2017-06-07, 2017-07-19 + 42 ,3)  #linspace(start, end, num)
y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)
3rd_y_intercept = y_axis[2]
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.plot(x[0], y[0], 'go')
plt.plot(x[1], y[1], 'go')
plt.show()
```

But am getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:/Coding/Line.py", line3, in
>
> coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
>
> File "C:\Users\Arjun\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 546, in polyfit
>       x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'float'
>   But i dont know how to convert Index of type Timestamp to use it in polynomial.

**Note:** the x co-ordinates are derived from Dataframe's index. and am using datetime module.
Please help, and am ready to use different method to draw line in place of polynomial fit.

Comment: `x = [2017-06-07 00:00:00, 2017-07-19 00:00:00]` will throw SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: @OwlMax i have working code, i just pasted in here to make it more easier to understand in simpler form.

Comment: Please just provide the minimum working example. Otherwise nobody can help. Remove everything not necessary to answer your question, e.g just keep the addition and the Timestamp object. Try to explain why you need to make an addition in the first place. Then I'm sure you will have correct and useful answer.

Comment: `x = [2017-06-07, 2017-07-19]` evaluates to `x = [2004,1991]`. The code does not match the error reported. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638137/curve-fitting-to-a-time-series-in-the-formate-datetime, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093496/problems-in-pandas-datetime-convert-to-num, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956127/trendline-plotting-not-working-with-bigdataset

Comment: @OwlMax Thanks for the guidance ,since am new to this site..i dont know much of the environment.

Comment: @BlueQuant, np. Please don't see the downvote as punishment but rather as a possible improvement for writing better question. SO's community can be a bit harsh to newcomers sometimes. Just keep up the effort! IMO, It's worth it on the long term.

Comment: @OwlMax hah, no problem whatsoever, i'll take it in a positive way and i'll keep up with the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.polyfit` is clearly expecting pure numeric values.  You can convert yours like this:

```
coefficients = np.polyfit(np.asarray(x).astype(float), y, 1)
```

That will convert your timestamps to some sort of epoch time, and then you can do the fit and convert back to timestamps if you need to (more likely you will convert other X values to floats using the same logic so you can make predictions using the model).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i replaced with what you told..it is throwing AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'. am new to python, so can you please elaborate, any help will be appreciated, Thanks again.

Comment: @BlueQuant: OK, I updated my answer.  I didn't realize your actual input was not a NumPy array.  Now it should work.

Comment: Now it say, float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' :(

Comment: @BlueQuant: Why don't you post a full, actual working sample program with actual sample data?  Right now the sample you posted is not runnable, valid Python.

Comment: its a bit longer and maybe hard to read for others, right now am trying to replace timestamp indexes with 0s and 1s indexes..if problem still persists, i'll post the full program.

Comment: I see.  You're fitting a line between two 2D points.  You don't neeed a function for this at all--just do it manually!  It's super easy to find the slope of a line between two points, right?  Just subtract and divide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150002/discussion-between-bluequant-and-john-zwinck).

Comment: This link has the full program, any help will make me happy 10x. 
 https://gist.github.com/RJUNS/f2b81a4d027033cea03bceacc43a3eb5

Answer (score -1):

If the function doesn't support datetimes then it may be simplest to convert them to floats (eg. seconds since t0).

Comment: can you please explain how to do it?